# Where are the gesture recognizers for the iOS 13 undo/redo gestures?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, ios13, undo

New in iOS 13, three gestures are interpreted as asking for undo and redo:

- Double tap with three fingers means undo.
- Swipe left with three fingers means undo.
- Swift right with three fingers means redo.

Where are the gesture recognizers that detect these gestures? What would I do to override them, turn them off, or arbitrate between them and my own gestures?

Comment: Looks like there's a private class called `UIUndoGestureRecognizer` that is attached to a `UIEditingOverlayGestureView` which lives in a `UIInputSetContainerView` inside a `UITextEffectsWindow`. I imagine you could use the methods in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to determine whether your gestures should require these to fail or not, or should be recognized simultaneously with them, etc. (I haven't looked into this too deeply so I'm not providing this as an answer.)

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler I wish you'd give this as an answer! That is _exactly_ what I wanted to know. Whether I can manipulate them or not, those are the gesture recognizers I was looking for. Well done.

Comment: Oh okay! Yeah I'll add it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there's a private class called `UIUndoGestureRecognizer` that is attached to a `UIEditingOverlayGestureView` which lives in a `UIInputSetContainerView` inside a `UITextEffectsWindow`. (To figure this out, I put a breakpoint inside an `UndoManager`'s `registerUndo` handler and tried swiping left with three fingers, then poked around in the resulting stack trace and assembly code until I found the gesture recognizer instance.)

You could probably use the methods in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to arbitrate between your gesture recognizers and these system ones, and you could override `editingInteractionConfiguration` in your view controller or view to return `.none` in order to just turn them off completely.

Comment: So there's an invisible window in front of my window, and its job (or one of its jobs) is to hold six gesture recognizers that detect these gestures. That's exactly what I wanted to know! I got a listing of them by pausing at a breakpoint and saying `UIApplication.shared.windows[1].subviews[0].subviews[1].gestureRecognizers`. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @matt yikes that works to access the recognizers, but makes me nervous! I am disabling apple's and replacing them on the main window with my own two/three finger tap gestures for a PencilKit app. Hopefully in the future apple provides api access to these gesture recognizers so I can sleep better...

Answer (score 1):

## To detect when user performs the undo/redo gestures:

It is unified through the system, So it is completely free if you are using `UndoManager`([More details](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/UndoManager.html)) or `NSUndoManager`. So if you implement it like the use shakes, it works for the gesture too.

## To change the behavior of the gesture (to prevent conflicting with other gestures of the app)

You can change the configuration of it with this variable:

```
public protocol UIResponder {
    var editingInteractionConfiguration: UIEditingInteractionConfiguration
}
```

it is an enum:

```
public enum UIEditingInteractionConfiguration {
    case `default` // System behavior 
    case none // Disable
}
```

So it would be *disable* like:

```
override var editingInteractionConfiguration: UIEditingInteractionConfiguration { .none }
```

### Sorce:

WWDC 2019 - [Modernizing Your UI for iOS 13 - 37:00](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224?time=2216)

**Note that** there are bunch of more gestures in iOS 13, for example pinching 3 fingers **in** will copy the selected text and pinch them **out** will paste it. All of them connected to the old style actions (for example the classic *shake* action) alongside with this protocol and you can override it in any `responder`.

Apple call all of these *Editing Gestures* and you can see [the session here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/?time=2149)

## Note:

Some of the information in that session is not purely true, (for example `UIResponder` is not a `protocol`, it's a `class` actually) as @matt mentioned in the comments. But I have added the source of this answer and you can judge yourself.

Comment: Makes no sense. This is not "under UndoManager" and there is no UIResponder _protocol_. And this does not explain who / what is detecting the gesture when I make one. I know how an undo manager _works_. I know how a gesture (like shake) finds it and calls its `undo` or `redo`. The question is where the gesture is detected by the runtime.

Comment: I added the source of my answer. check it out @matt

Comment: Modernizing Your Audio App has nothing to do with this and does not have 37 minutes (it is less than 2 minutes long).

Comment: That's fine, I've seen that video. (1) It's wrong. There is _still_ no protocol called UIResponder. It's a class. The code in the video is bogus. (2) I didn't ask how to turn off the whole feature. I want to know, under the hood, how is the runtime seeing these individual gestures? I looked through the view hierarchy for gesture recognizers that might be doing this, but I can't find them.

Comment: Sorry, I have noted that in the answer and make the points of it more bold for readers. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Ok but this does not tell me anything I didn’t know and it does not answer the question I asked. I’ve got an undo manager, it responds to the gestures, etc. Now I want to understand this mechanism more deeply.